# Delete nested fields from all/multiple documents in a collection - NodeJS + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

While learning mongoDB + NodeJs, i was trying the following:

From the below documents, delete the "**position**" field.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"613627e67b73faaebcb3960a"},"name":"Example 1","address":"Highway 1","documentType":null,"personalDetails":{"gender":"male","age":{"$numberInt":"23"},"position":null}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"613627e67b73faaebcb3960b"},"name":"Example 2","address":"Highway 2","documentType":"details","personalDetails":{"gender":"male","age":{"$numberInt":"23"},"position":null}}
```

I was able to figure out how to delete the **address** field using the below code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "URI";


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("sample_airbnb");
  dbo.collection("customers").updateMany({}, {$unset: {"address": 1}}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

However, when i pass "position" instead of "address" nothing happens. What am i doing wrong here?

My second question on top of this would be, if i passed an array of fields, Eg:

```
var arr1 = new Array();
var arr2 = ["position", "documentType"];
```

How would i delete the above defined fields in the array from all documents?

I have not reached the second bit, since i was stuck with the first part.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to try this syntax from the MongoDB Manual for referring the embedded field: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents

Comment: $unset :{"personalDetails.position":null}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my both the parts of my problem by using the below piece of code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
var url = "URI";


MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("sample_airbnb");

  dbo.collection("customers").find().forEach(function (doc) {
    var docKeysArray = [];
    docKeysArray = getDeepKeys(doc);
    //console.log(docKeysArray);
    if (doc.name == 'Example 1') {
      //console.log(doc);
      var fieldsArrayToUse = "BRA"
      deleteFields(fieldsArrayToUse, docKeysArray, doc);
    }
  });
});

function deleteFields(fieldsArrayToUse, docKeysArray, doc) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("sample_airbnb");
    var fieldsArray = [];
    if (fieldsArrayToUse == "AUS") {
      fieldsArray = ["address", "gender"];
    }
    else if (fieldsArrayToUse == "BRA") {
      fieldsArray = ["position", "documentType"];
    }
    fieldsArray.forEach(function (field) {
      console.log('.*' + field + '$');
      const fieldRegex = new RegExp('.*' + field + '$');
      docKeysArray.forEach(function (docKey) {
        if ((fieldRegex.test(docKey))) {
          if (err) throw err;
          dbo.collection('customers').updateOne({ "_id": new ObjectId(doc._id) }, { $unset: { [docKey]: "" } },).then((obj) => {
            console.log('Updated');
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

function getDeepKeys(obj) {
  var keys = [];
  const idRegex = new RegExp('_id.*');
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (!(idRegex.test(key))) { //exclude the id fields from the final keys array
      keys.push(key);
      if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
        var subkeys = getDeepKeys(obj[key]);
        keys = keys.concat(subkeys.map(function (subkey) {
          return key + "." + subkey;
        }));
      }
    }
  }
  return keys;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
{
  "$unset": {
    "personalDetails.position": ""
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```